# Renaming the Parent node and Rearranging the Child nodes simultaneously in xml using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to rename the parent node and rearrange the child nodes simultaneously.

I tried some code but was unable to get the desired output.

This was the output that i was getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">

<Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <Run xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run">

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>02</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>03</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

      </Run>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I wanted to remove the namespaces, rename the Parent tags and rearrange the child tags.
So i used this code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="A3" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="A4" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="A2" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="A1" />

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename RunObject to Item -->
  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was able to remove the namespaces, rename the parent tags but was unable to rearrange the child tags. The output i got was this

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>

  <Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <Document>

      <Item>
        <A1>NA</A1>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A1>NA</A1>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A3>03</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
      </Item>

    </Document>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

But the desired output is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>

  <Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <Document>

      <Item>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A3>03</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A1>NA</A1>
      </Item>

    </Document>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem #1**:
You have two templates matching the same nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
```

Only the last one of these will be applied.

**Problem #2**:
The elements `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and `A4` are in a namespace inherited from their `Run` ancestor. You need to use the prefix bound to that namespace when selecting them.

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename RunObject to Item + reorder child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A3" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A4" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A2" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A1" />
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```